# Stuck on Project Dagger: What do I do next?

Tags: rage-2

I am playing *Rage 2*. It seems that I have completed all the tasks other than Project Dagger.

From the screenshot below, it's clear I've completed the three main tasks. However, I can't see what I am supposed to do next. I don't see any locations on the map I need to travel to.

If it helps (and this may be a **SPOILER**) — I got to an Authority base, pulled the head off the baddie (the guy pictured in the bottom right of the screenshot), and gave it to an old man (pictured in blue, top right of the screenshot) who seemed to want to analyse it. I'm assuming that I have not actually completed the game?

[image: screenshot described above]

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not done yet but you have to complete the quest lines for Marshall and Loosum also.

EDIT

You're over level 5 with all of them and assuming you have no quests left for any then this may be a bug as reported by many other players. Some people got it moving by reinstalling, some people by fast travelling.

Comment: This answer is vague. In the screenshot above, it looks as if "Return to Marshall" and "Return to Loosum" have been completed. Could you provide more detail as to what exactly needs to be done?

Comment: Yes - I should have zoomed in on those tiny checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what a "quest line" is :(  (if it helps, the picture I provided can be clicked to maximise) .. I have fast travelled multiple times so it looks like a re-install is my next option

Comment: It means all the named missions that the people there give you to do.

Comment: I ran into a similar bug. Hopefully OP has not ran into my one. The solution was an entire purge of the game. The game is buggy as all hell, and unfortunately, it very much does still contain game-breaking bugs.

Comment: *shrugs* That's Bethesda!

Comment: I re-installed, I have fast travelled. I still don't get any additional quest(s) :/ - is there a place I need to fast travel too or just fast travel in general?

Comment: Don't know, just saw someone mention that fast travel fixed it for them.